# Why does Naive Bayes not work in Spark MLlib Pipeline like Logistic Regression?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, nlp, apache-spark-mllib

I am working on a problem in sentiment analysis for tweets using Spark with Scala.  I have a working version utilizing a logistic regression model as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.HashingTF
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType};
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.{NaiveBayes, NaiveBayesModel}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{CountVectorizer, RegexTokenizer, StopWordsRemover}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2Vec
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

// Sentiment140 training corpus
val trainFile = "s3://someBucket/training.1600000.processed.noemoticon.csv"
val swFile = "s3://someBucket/stopwords.txt"
val tr = sc.textFile(trainFile)
val stopwords: Array[String] = sc.textFile(swFile).flatMap(_.stripMargin.split("\\s+")).collect ++ Array("rt")

val parsed = tr.filter(_.contains("\",\"")).map(_.split("\",\"").map(_.replace("\"", ""))).filter(row => row.forall(_.nonEmpty)).map(row => (row(0).toDouble, row(5))).filter(row => row._1 != 2).map(row => (row._1 / 4, row._2)) 
val pDF = parsed.toDF("label","tweet") 
val tokenizer = new RegexTokenizer().setGaps(false).setPattern("\\p{L}+").setInputCol("tweet").setOutputCol("words")
val filterer = new StopWordsRemover().setStopWords(stopwords).setCaseSensitive(false).setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("filtered")
val countVectorizer = new CountVectorizer().setInputCol("filtered").setOutputCol("features")

val lr = new LogisticRegression().setMaxIter(50).setRegParam(0.2).setElasticNetParam(0.0) 
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenizer, filterer, countVectorizer, lr))

val lrModel = pipeline.fit(pDF)

// Now model is made.  Lets get some test data...

val testFile = "s3://someBucket/testdata.manual.2009.06.14.csv"
val te = sc.textFile(testFile)
val teparsed = te.filter(_.contains("\",\"")).map(_.split("\",\"").map(_.replace("\"", ""))).filter(row => row.forall(_.nonEmpty)).map(row => (row(0).toDouble, row(5))).filter(row => row._1 != 2).map(row => (row._1 / 4, row._2)) 
val teDF = teparsed.toDF("label","tweet")

val res = lrModel.transform(teDF)
val restup = res.select("label","prediction").rdd.map(r => (r(1).asInstanceOf[Double], r(0).asInstanceOf[Double]))
val metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(restup)

metrics.areaUnderROC()
```

Using logistic regression, this returns a perfectly normal AUC.  However, when I switch from logistic regression to val nb = new NaiveBayes(), I get the following error:

```
found   : org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.NaiveBayes
required: org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage
   val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenizer, filterer, countVectorizer, nb))
```

In consulting with the API docs on the MLlib [PipelineStage](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage) lists both logistic regression and Naive Bayes are both listed as subclasses.  So why does LR work and not NB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you use incorrect class. With Pipelines use:

```
org.apache.spark.ml.NaiveBayes
```

and consult [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#naive-bayes) for the correct syntax.

Comment: Ah.  The pipelines do not work for the older .mllib packages (which I was using with NB from some legacy code) but do work for the .ml packages (which I was using for the LR model).  One slight correction to the above... it is org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes.

Comment: I wonder why it would take my sloppy use of packages with HashingTF also coming from mllib instead of ml?  Ah well.  :)